# RethinkDb Join array in object with objects

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, reql

I'm using rethinkdb with JS.

I have a rethinkdb table 'users'. One user object looks like this:

```
{
  id: '1',
  friends: [
    '2',
    '4'
  ],
  items: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'test item 1'
    }
  ]
}
```

A user is allowed to see all items of himself and of his friends.
Now I want to get all items a user is allowed to see.

But I don't now how to do that. With a join or with a merge?
Or is my data structure wrong?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all friends with [`getAll`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get_all/) and then [`map`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get_all/) items:

```
r.db("YourDataBase").table("YoorTable")
    .getAll(r.args(r.db("YourDataBase").table("YoorTable").get("a1")("friends")))
    .map(function(val){
      return val("items");
    })
```